# Sound will not play from jar, but only when i run it from NetBeans. (Javazoom player)

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-8

I have downloaded and imported JLayer 1.0.1
(http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html)

and using this code i can play sound if i run it from NetBeans

```
package window;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.AudioDevice;
import javazoom.jl.player.FactoryRegistry;
import javazoom.jl.player.advanced.AdvancedPlayer;

/**
 * Provide basic playing of MP3 files via the javazoom library.
 * See http://www.javazoom.net/
 * 
 * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */
public class MusicPlayer
{
    // The current player. It might be null.
    private AdvancedPlayer player;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MusicFilePlayer
     */
    public MusicPlayer()
    {
        player = null;
    }

    /**
     * Play a part of the given file.
     * The method returns once it has finished playing.
     * @param filename The file to be played.
     */
    public void playSample(String filename)
    {
        try {
            setupPlayer(filename);
            player.play(500);
        }
        catch(JavaLayerException e) {
            reportProblem(filename);
        }
        finally {
            killPlayer();
        }
    }    

    /**
     * Start playing the given audio file.
     * The method returns once the playing has been started.
     * @param filename The file to be played.
     */
    public void startPlaying(final String filename)
    {
        try {
            setupPlayer(filename);
            Thread playerThread = new Thread() {
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        player.play(5000);
                    }
                    catch(JavaLayerException e) {
                        reportProblem(filename);
                    }
                    finally {
                        killPlayer();
                    }
                }
            };
            playerThread.start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            reportProblem(filename);
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        killPlayer();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the player ready to play the given file.
     * @param filename The name of the file to play.
     */
    private void setupPlayer(String filename)
    {
        try {
            InputStream is = getInputStream(filename);
            player = new AdvancedPlayer(is, createAudioDevice());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            reportProblem(filename);
            killPlayer();
        }
        catch(JavaLayerException e) {
            reportProblem(filename);
            killPlayer();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return an InputStream for the given file.
     * @param filename The file to be opened.
     * @throws IOException If the file cannot be opened.
     * @return An input stream for the file.
     */
    private InputStream getInputStream(String filename)
        throws IOException
    {
        return new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(filename));
    }

    /**
     * Create an audio device.
     * @throws JavaLayerException if the device cannot be created.
     * @return An audio device.
     */
    private AudioDevice createAudioDevice()
        throws JavaLayerException
    {
        return FactoryRegistry.systemRegistry().createAudioDevice();
    }

    /**
     * Terminate the player, if there is one.
     */
    private void killPlayer()
    {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(player != null) {
                player.stop();
                player = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Report a problem playing the given file.
     * @param filename The file being played.
     */
    private void reportProblem(String filename)
    {
        System.out.println("There was a problem playing: " + filename);
    }

}
```

which i can call it from another class like this

```
private MusicPlayer player = new MusicPlayer();
player.startPlaying("src/audio/SuperheroKeygen.mp3");
```

The audio file is imported to the project as well.

But i get no audio if i run the .jar

If i open the .jar file with Winrar, i get immediatly a folder audio with my mp3 in it so the mp3 is included at the .jar

Running jar from command line gives me

> There was a problem playing: src/audio/SuperheroKeygen.mp3
>   Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at window.MusicPlayer$1.run(MusicPlayer.java:64)

P.S Java Newbie

Comment: I assume your JAR doesn't have a folder next to it called src, which contains a folder called audio, which contains a file called SuperheroKeygen.mp3, because that's where your program is looking for the sound file.

Comment: player.startPlaying("SuperheroKeygen.mp3"); remove url path, just give it a file name, This file should be in the same directory where you are trying to run jar file.  Doing this you will know What is the issue. Path Issue or else

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is probably not a file path that your player can access. You can do a couple of things. You might have to copy the file out to your local disk like this:

```
Path soundPath = Files.createTempFile("SuperheroKeygen", ".mp3");
try (InputStream jarSound= getClass().getResourceAsStream("/src/audio/SuperheroKeygen.mp3")){
    Files.copy(jarSound, soundPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);        
} catch (IOException e){
    //handle the exception
}
```

Then `soundPath` contains the path to the sound file you can pass to your player.

It's possible that you only need to change it so that in your `getInputStream` method, you just use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` to get your `InputStream`instead of creating a new `FileInputStream`. If you do that, you'll have to start your resource path with a `/` so that it goes from the root and not the current package directory:

```
private InputStream getInputStream(String filename) throws IOException {
    return new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename));
}
```

You can use the ClassLoader to make it read all filenames as absolute paths so you don't need the leading `/` like so:

```
private InputStream getInputStream(String filename) throws IOException {
    return new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename));
}
```